# Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::getPaymentDetails(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I have a problem regarding to my project, I have one customer that can have several bookings.

Here is the model of my Order and Customer

```
// class Customer extends Model

public function orders () {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

and ..

```
//class Order extends Model

public function customer () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'customer_id');
}

public function orderdetail () {
    return $this -> hasOne('App\OrderDetail');
}
```

So after the customer make a booking, I want to show the booking details in the payment details page ..

what do I have to do in my controller

I do this in my controller but i results some error

```
public function getPaymentDetails($id) {
  $ordered = $this -> order -> where ('order_id', $id) -> with ('orderdetail') -> get();
  return view ('paymentdetail', ['orders' => $ordered]);
}
```

Comment: How you are accessing this `getPaymentDetails($id)`, I mean are you passing the `$id` value?

Comment: I don't know, I still confuse that's why I asked in here .. How can I show the data in getPaymentDetails.. I'm new in laravel

Comment: Please post you routing too where you've mentioned `getPaymentDetails`

Answer (score 0):

you should pass your id like this from view

```
  <a href="{{ route('your_route', $class->id) }}" class="btn btn-info pull-left" style="margin-right: 3px;">Edit</a>

and your route

Route::get('/your_route/{id}', [
    'as' => 'your_route', 'uses' => 'Yourcontroller@yourmethod'
]);
```